# MySQL Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint -- MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

When forward Engineering in MySQL Workbench I get the following error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `sdosburn_guile`.`Employee`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile`.`Employee` (
      `EmployeeID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `IsManager` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
      `PasswordHash` BLOB(256) NOT NULL,
      `NameLast` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      `NameFirst` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      `DateofBirth` DATE NOT NULL,
      `EmailAddress` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
      `Gender` TINYINT(1) NULL,
      `HireDate` DATE NULL,
      `_WarehouseID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeID`),
      INDEX `fk_Employee_Warehouse1_idx` (`_WarehouseID` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_Employee_Warehouse1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`_WarehouseID`)
        REFERENCES `sdosburn_guile`.`Warehouse` (`WarehouseID`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 10 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Attached is my DB information. I've checked data types, size, and everything else I've looked up on the Web, please help!!!!!

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE,         SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema sdosburn_guile
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema sdosburn_guile
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema named
-- -----------------------------------------------------
USE `sdosburn_guile` ;
```

---

-- Table `sdosburn_guile`.`Customer`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile`.`Customer` (
`CustomerID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`PasswordHash` BLOB(256) NOT NULL,
`NameLast` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`NameFirst` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
`DateofBirth` DATE NULL,
`EmailAddress` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(13) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `sdosburn_guile`.`Book`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile`.`Book` (
`ItemID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`Title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Author` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Genre` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
`ReleaseDate` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
`Publisher` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ItemID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `sdosburn_guile`.`Music`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile`.`Music` (
`ItemID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`Title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Artist` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Genre` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
`ReleaseDate` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
`Record Company` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ItemID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `sdosburn_guile`.`Movie`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile`.`Movie` (
`ItemID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
`Title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Genre` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
`ReleaseDate` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
`Actor_1` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`Actor_2` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`Actor_3` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`Director` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`Production Company` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ItemID`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `sdosburn_guile`.`Warehouse`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile`.`Warehouse` (
`WarehouseID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
`_ManageID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`WarehouseID`),
INDEX `fk_Warehouse_Employee1_idx` (`_ManageID` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Warehouse_Employee1`
FOREIGN KEY (`_ManageID`)
REFERENCES `sdosburn_guile`.`Employee` (`EmployeeID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `sdosburn_guile`.`Employee`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile`.`Employee` (
`EmployeeID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`IsManager` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
`PasswordHash` BLOB(256) NOT NULL,
`NameLast` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`NameFirst` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`DateofBirth` DATE NOT NULL,
`EmailAddress` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
`Gender` TINYINT(1) NULL,
`HireDate` DATE NULL,
`_WarehouseID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeID`),
INDEX `fk_Employee_Warehouse1_idx` (`_WarehouseID` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Employee_Warehouse1`
FOREIGN KEY (`_WarehouseID`)
REFERENCES `sdosburn_guile`.`Warehouse` (`WarehouseID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `sdosburn_guile`.`Address`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile`.`Address` (
`AddressID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Number` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`Street` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`State` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`Secondary` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
`LocalCustomerID` INT NULL,
`LocalEmployeeID` INT NULL,
`LocalWarehouseID` INT NULL,
`Addresscol` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`AddressID`),
INDEX `fk_Address_Customer_idx` (`LocalCustomerID` ASC),
INDEX `fk_Address_Employee1_idx` (`LocalEmployeeID` ASC),
INDEX `fk_Address_Warehouse1_idx` (`LocalWarehouseID` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `LocalCustomerID_UNIQUE` (`LocalCustomerID` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `LocalEmployeeID_UNIQUE` (`LocalEmployeeID` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `Addresscol_UNIQUE` (`Addresscol` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Address_Customer`
FOREIGN KEY (`LocalCustomerID`)
REFERENCES `sdosburn_guile`.`Customer` (`CustomerID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Address_Employee1`
FOREIGN KEY (`LocalEmployeeID`)
REFERENCES `sdosburn_guile`.`Employee` (`EmployeeID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Address_Warehouse1`
FOREIGN KEY (`LocalWarehouseID`)
REFERENCES `sdosburn_guile`.`Warehouse` (`WarehouseID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `sdosburn_guile`.`Billing`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile`.`Billing` (
`BillingID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Remove datatype and have key be the payment name?',
`_CustomerID` INT NOT NULL,
 `PaymentType` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`PaymentName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User\'s name for payment method',
`AccountNumber` VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Can be card number or bank account number',
`Routing Number` VARCHAR(9) NULL,
`CVV` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
`_BillingAddressID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`BillingID`),
INDEX `fk_Billing_Customer1_idx` (`_CustomerID` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `BillingID_UNIQUE` (`BillingID` ASC),
INDEX `fk_Billing_Address1_idx` (`_BillingAddressID` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Billing_Customer1`
FOREIGN KEY (`_CustomerID`)
REFERENCES `sdosburn_guile`.`Customer` (`CustomerID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_Billing_Address1`
FOREIGN KEY (`_BillingAddressID`)
REFERENCES `sdosburn_guile`.`Address` (`AddressID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

-- Table `sdosburn_guile`.`ShoppingCart`

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdosburn_guile`.`ShoppingCart` (
`CartID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`_CustomerID` INT NOT NULL,
INDEX `fk_ShoppingCart_Customer1_idx` (`_CustomerID` ASC),
PRIMARY KEY (`CartID`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_ShoppingCart_Customer1`
FOREIGN KEY (`_CustomerID`)
REFERENCES `sdosburn_guile`.`Customer` (`CustomerID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

....

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: One tip is to create the ones that are independent and parent like first, then the children. It is not as if you are narrowing it down much. And the order is darn important. Do the parents first.

Answer (score 0):

Your Foreign Key `_ManageID` in the Warehouse table is not a primary key in another table, that's why you're running into an error. Once you fix that, you should be ok, but I haven't verified it.

Answer (score 0):

For those that have this issue but everything looks to be perfectly fine.  What worked for me is dropping all tables and running the forward engineer script again.